# How do I determine the highest and lowest value using do while loops

Tags: c++

I am currently stuck in my homework and the problem is that I need to create a program that will ask for 5 integer numbers from which I should determine the highest and lowest value. I am quite confused as of now, and my initial code is this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

 int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,min=0,max=0;

 cout << " Enter 1st number : ";
 cin >> num1;
 cout << " Enter 2nd number : ";
 cin >> num2;
 cout << " Enter 3rd number : ";
 cin >> num3;
 cout << " Enter 4th number : ";
 cin >> num4;
 cout << " Enter 5th number : ";
 cin >> num5;
 do{
    if(num1<num2 && num1<num3 && num1<num4 && num1<num5 ){
    max = num1;}
    if(num2<num1 && num2<num3 && num2<num4 && num2<num5 ){
    max = num2;}
    if(num3<num1 && num3<num2 && num3<num4 && num3<num5 ){
    max = num3;}
    if(num4<num1 && num4<num3 && num4<num2 && num4<num5 ){
    max = num4;}
    if(num5<num1 && num5<num3 && num5<num4 && num5<num2 ){
    max = num2;}
 }while(max>0);
 cout << " The highest number is : " <<max;


return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what an array is?

Comment: Take a look at [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), assuming your assignment permits it.

Comment: @NathanOliver my professor told us to only use do while and if since we are not yet on arrays

Comment: Arrays, or vectors as they are called in c++, make this task a lot simpler.  You could watch a tutorial for this [here](https://youtu.be/Cq1h1KPoGBU). I'm sure the professor won't mind if you come up with an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use `std::max` and `std::min`, you can use:

```
max = std::max({num1, num2, num3, num4, num5});
min = std::min({num1, num2, num3, num4, num5});
```

to simplify the code in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should store your numbers into a `std::vector<int>` or `std::array` and then use the [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) algorithm to obtain the largest and smallest number.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution without using arrays.
I'd suggest you to try it yourself before. You don't learn when you just copy code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i=0, num, min=INT_MAX, max=INT_MIN;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> num;
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < 5);

        std::cout << "The max number is: " << max << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The min number is: " << min << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. Just changed max from initally 0 to -FP_INFINITE. Now it should work

Comment: Why not `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` as the values.  I don't think `FP_INFINITE` is going to give you the right value.

Comment: I tested both (FP_INFINITE and INT_MAX/INT_MIN) and for me, both just worked fine. But I'm also very new to c++ so I don't really know which one fits better

Comment: I get 1 for its value [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f8a5087ef905441) so it isn't a portable solution.

Comment: You are right I changed it. Thank you for your testing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to remember, you can loop for e.g. 5 times, then have a comparison before asking the next number.

so generally (idea, write it yourself and learn):

for (5 times)
 ask user input, save as input
 if largest number is null, then equal to input
 else if largest number is smaller, then set input equal to largest number

Continue for loop times.

Comment: Instead of setting the largest number to null you should just check if it is the first iteration.  If it is then the first number entered is the largest number, otherwise compare the number entered to the largest number.  Besides that this is a great answer.  It actually solves the problem the most efficiently.

Comment: I usually try to avoid making it check for 0/first iteration as you might want to make it so that you previously set a largest number but that's not happening in this case, so both are right. /shrug

Comment: The problem with giving the largest number an initial value is if the user enters all numbers lower than that then you give them the wrong number.  If you set it to "null" (0) and I enter `-1, -2 ,-3` then I'll get 0 as the max and not -1.  So you either have to check if it is the first iteration, ask for the first number before the loop and then only loop 4 times, or set the largest number to the smallest it can be.

Comment: No, what I mean by that is if you save it previously, e.g. you take it from some storage or previously entered number, you can get the new numbers and compare it to old. Just makes it so if I come back  and add features, I never have to worry about editing old stuff. I do not mean giving it a value to begin with.

Another way of doing above is to ask for first number before entering loop, thereby avoiding the empty check.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than compare all the numbers each time. Simply compare your current smallest against the numbers in sequence.

```
int data[5];
// read numbers into data.

int min = data[0];   // Guess that number 0 is the smallst number.

// Now check if the guess is correct and update if you are wrong.
for(int loop = 0; loop < 5; ++loop)
{
     // check if data[loop] is smaller than your current guess.
     // if it is smaller than update your guess.
     // when you have checked all the values exit the loop.
}
std::cout << "Smallest: " << min << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a loop to do this you can do that without it else if it's necessary to use a loop you must use an array or some other data structure